# Is it possible to reverse a flag on a post?

Tags: support, flags

I recently flagged [a post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16343/does-xbox-360-usb-controller-work-out-of-the-box-on-windows-linux-mac) as a duplicate *before* reading the entirely of the post that I indicated was the original question (yeah, I know, bad Shaun). After reading, however, I realized the original question was just a subset of the new question and that the new question deserved to be asked. However, I saw no method via which I could reverse my hasty action. I could try to flag it again, it seems, but not un-flag it.

Is this possible, or should I just treat this as a learning experience and "slow my roll" next time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope! Flagging is irreversible.

All that will happen is that your flag will be dismissed by a moderator, probably with no action if there was no need for it.